# How to add and use MarkdownView android library

Tags: java, android, markdown

I am on Android Studio 1.5.1

[**falnatsheh/MarkdownView**](https://github.com/falnatsheh/MarkdownView)

In the project's readme at github its gives instructions for use. These  don't cover actually adding the project .. and I am learning Android programming (in fact I am making an app to keep my notes, as a sort of second step after "hello world").

how do I add it to the project so that I can follow the instructions on the project's readme? My default attempt was to follow these [instructions](http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-studio-add-library-project/):

File -> New -> Import Module .. add as ":markdownview" in my case, add it to the app's build.gradle, and then that should be it according to the site.

But that doesn't work:[image: cannot resolve symbol 'MarkdownView']

The project's readme starts by saying you should add "compile 'us.feras.mdv:markdownview:1.1.0'" to the dependencies file (I am assuming they mean the Module:app one)... which looks like another way to add ":markdownview" to me.. but I did that too (and that instead of the ":markdownview"). Still the symbol does not resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how do I add it to the project so that I can follow the instructions on the project's readme?

Add the following to your `app/build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies { 
    compile 'us.feras.mdv:markdownview:1.1.0'
}
```

> which looks like another way to add ":markdownview" to me

Not exactly, but close.

> but I did that too (and that instead of the ":markdownview"). Still the symbol does not resolve.

As with everything else in Java, you need to add an `import` statement.

I just created a scrap project in Android Studio, accepting all defaults in the new-project wizard. I pasted the above snippet in `app/build.gradle` and let Android Studio sync with the project files. I then added a reference to `MarkdownView` in the Java file, and Android Studio picked up the import without issue.

Comment: as you can tell if you read my post, I did that. I actually did that first, I just retold it from memory and worked backwards in my description. I did *not* add the "dependencies" itself as a separate node iin the gradle, I just added the interior line to the dependencies that are already there. Perhaps there is a problem with using File->Import Module ? Or there is some specific difference in getting it up in a Master/Detail Flow project?

Comment: @robertotomás: "I just added the interior line to the dependencies that are already there" -- that should be fine. "Perhaps there is a problem with using File->Import Module ?" -- not in general. Now, the guy who wrote the library checked in the `.idea/` directory, which was not a good move, and so that might interfere with matters for importing the module. But, unless you plan on modifying the library code itself, I'd just depend upon the artifact, per the instructions. "Or there is some specific difference in getting it up in a Master/Detail Flow project?" -- none that I am aware of.

Comment: @robertotomás: I suggest that you do what I outlined in the last paragraph of my answer. Create a scrap project in Android Studio that you can use for experimentation. Add the `compile` line to `dependencies`, then let Android Studio sync the project with the Gradle files (you should get a yellow banner for this; if not, do it manually from the Tools > Android menu). Then, you should be able to add an `import` for it in the Java file, etc.

Comment: aay, see that was it, you were right. I'm not even thinking to add `import us.feras.mdv.MarkdownView` in the code. If you edit your response and trim the chaff at the top (and maybe be a little more clear by saying something like "you also have to `import` the library in the Activity/Fragment you are editing"), it would make me much happier marking this as the answer.